# Can't render an img by setting its src to returned MVC action response data from jQuery request

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have this jQuery code inside a view:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('input', '#usernameTextBox', function () {
        $.get(
            '@Url.Action("GetCAPTCHAImage")',
            { username: $("#usernameTextBox").val() },
            function (data) {
                $("#captchaImage").height(50);
                $("#captchaImage").width(400);
                $("#captchaImage").attr("src", "data:image/png, " + data);
            }
        );
    });
})
```

The action it calls is this (it works, I can browse to this action in my web browser to view the generated image and Google Chrome displays it just fine without any complaints):

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetCAPTCHAImage(string username)
{
    try
    {
        return File(GenerateCaptcha(username, 40, 50), "image/png");
    }
    catch
    {
        return File(new byte[] { 0 }, "image/png");
    }
}
```

The jQuery logic grabs an image from my controller's action and then tries to set the source of the following `<img/>` element to it:

```
<img id="captchaImage" />
```

The problem is that it won't render the image, but I see the data gets returned and everything:

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Well the problem is that you are returning a file, and you put it as a "string" directly as the src

Comment: @ZivWeissman What should I return it as in order to get it to render?

Comment: You either need to save the Captcha on your machine first, then return the location of it, or you can render the data returned as an image... try looking at - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6033452/rendering-imagestream-object-using-jquery

Comment: @ZivWeissman I got it working just now, but not like that, I returned a base 64 string instead. I'll post my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to return a base 64 string:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<string> GetCAPTCHAImage(string username)
{
    try
    {
        return Convert.ToBase64String(GenerateCaptcha(username, 40, 50));
    }
    catch
    {
        return String.Empty;
    }
}
```

Also, this was the wrong format as the image was `JFIF` or jpeg based (also note the `base64`):

```
$("#captchaImage").attr("src", "data:image/jpeg;base64," + data);
```